# Failed to load custom JS in Drupal

Tags: php, javascript, google-chrome, drupal

I need to use jquery ui tabs library but only in one add form. So i used `hook_form_alter()` to enable tabs and add my js:

```
drupal_add_library('system', 'ui.tabs');
drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'rating') .'/js/newad.js', 'file');
```

Library and script was correctly added into page head

and it is correctly available by this url but something wrong with it and it's not working:

[image: error screensot]

Wy Chrome is failed to load it?

contents of newad.js:

```
(function ($) {

    $(function() {
        $( ".select-format-ads" ).tabs();
    });

})(jQuery);
```

UPD: if i add `alert('test');` in begining nothing happens in Chrome, but works fine in Safari.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was resolve that. Problem causes by AdBlock extension of GoogleChrome because of term "ad" in js filename.

Answer was found [here in other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4390134/failed-to-load-resource-under-chrome)

So i just rename thet file an all seems work fine now.