# Chrome request fails (but works with Fiddler)

Tags: google-chrome, fiddler

I have a strange problem in Chrome 30, where Chrome fails to load an HTML (.aspx) page. It shows like this in the network tab:

[image: Pic1]

I have ALL extensions disabled, so it cannot be AdBlock or any other extension.
I tried to load the page in an iframe and also as a normal page, but the same problem occurs.

The headers of the request and the response are like this:

[image: Pic2]

I see no problems there...

I cannot understand, why this page is failing to load, while others load OK. As you can see, the page even returns the status code 200, but without any content. The page works fine in Firefox.

There is a p3p header for the use of IE, but it should be ignored by Chrome.

The page used to work in previous versions of Chrome, so it must be some recent update to Chrome (30 or some previous version).

Any idea, what might be the problem?

Comment: I tried also running chrome with --disable-web-security and it did not help. It must be something else.

Comment: One more interesting tidbit is that the request works, when I startup Fiddler (a web debugging proxy). :-\

Comment: Do you have the **Decode** option enabled in Fiddler? Do you see any *HTTP Protocol Violations* in Fiddler or its Log tab when you load the page in question?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer finally:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17171164/1196593

We were using Response.Close() in the ASP.NET page in question. Chrome does not seem to like it. I changed it to Response.End() and now it works. :-)

I don't know why it worked with Fiddler. Perhaps Fiddler made some change to network traffic, so that Chrome did not meet the problem caused by Response.Close().