# Chrome give error **Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED** while other browser load images

Tags: css, google-chrome

When I open my site in Google Chrome, it gives the error **failed to load resource** in the console. My images are not showing in Chrome but are fine on other browsers. How can I fix this issue? [image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had the same issue. I'm working on Windows 8.1 system and had the problem with almost every page in Google Chrome, IE 11 and Firefox.

This is what worked for me. Run CMD as administrator and execute the following commands:

```
ipconfig /flushdns
ipconfig /renew
ipconfig /registerdns
```

I did not have to restart my PC, but everything worked again and all pages on the internet were avalible again.

Answer (score 7):

As a quick test to see if that's your problem, start Chrome in incognito mode with extensions disabled (ctrl+shift+n) and see if your page works now. Note that by default all extensions will be already disabled in incognito mode unless you've specifically set them to run (via chrome://extensions).   [please refer to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4390134/failed-to-load-resource-under-chrome)

Comment: open my site in incognito mode but same result

Answer (score 3):

You might have to check your internet connection. Many a time, the data can't be fetched due to bad or no internet. Or open the site in incognito mode and check whether that works or not. If you are using any blocker extensions, disable and check again.
You can do that via (chrome://extensions).

Answer (score 2):

I've spent weeks fighting with this problem on 2 different unrelated computers, even unable to ping Yahoo.com and having variety of connectivity issues in web browsers, including "DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN" and "ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED". I've tried various ipconfig commands, restarting DNS client service, "netsh winsock reset", and other solutions found on the internet.

Finally I realized the only common thing on both my computers was Malwarebytes. After closing/exiting Malwarebytes the problem was solved. I am now able to ping and access every website. The solution, again, at least in my case: close Malwarebytes

I just contacted Malwarebytes support but in the meantime wanted to provide this possible solution here.

Answer (score 1):

This can be caused if the URL supplied is wrong, this was my case.