# jQuery Ajax get fail message like Chrome console

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm going to go crazy.

When I i jQuery Ajax function to a request, I get in console this error

```
OPTIONS [myURL] net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

It is possible to get the error text *net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED* in my JavaScript?

I read all documentation about jQuery Ajax but I can't understand where I can find this message.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What is the url ?

Comment: Please post your ajax calling code.

Comment: I doubt seeing the Ajax code would help as `ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED` is to do with your DNS not having that address

Comment: try in the error callback.

Comment: I think you should share your code for more inf.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28018617/chrome-give-error-failed-to-load-resource-neterr-name-not-resolved-while

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplified Ajax call. The URL is simply a variable of a WebService.

```
$.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: myURL,
    dataType: "json",
})
.done(function(response) {
    console.log(response)
})
.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.error("------AJAX error");
});
```