# Jquery boxslider won't load until I inspect element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on my portfolio which you can visit [here](http://mcsotiriou.com). `onclick` commands are for hiding and showing the different `div`s that are of my artwork.

I found a boxslider code to help show off my photographs, but when I initially load the page the frame is empty. It is only after I inspect the element that the pictures will appear.

I also keep on getting this error which I am pretty certain have something to do with the boxslider frame not loading my pictures:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null

Here is part of css of the boxslider frame:

```
.bx-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto 60px;
  padding: 0;
  *zoom: 1;
  -ms-touch-action: pan-y;
  touch-action: pan-y;
}
.bx-wrapper img {
  max-width: 90%;
  display: block;
}
.bxslider {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 auto;

}
ul.bxslider {
  list-style: none;
}
.bx-viewport {
  /*fix other elements on the page moving (on Chrome)*/
  -webkit-transform: translatez(0);
}
/** THEME
===================================*/
.bx-wrapper {
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #ccc;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #ccc;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #ccc;
  border: 5px solid #fff;
  background: #fff;
}
.bx-wrapper .bx-pager,
.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -30px;
  width: 100%;
}
/* LOADER */
.bx-wrapper .bx-loading {
  min-height: 50px;
  background: url('images/bx_loader.gif') center center no-repeat #ffffff;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2000;
}
/* PAGER */
.bx-wrapper .bx-pager {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: .85em;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #666;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
.bx-wrapper .bx-pager.bx-default-pager a {
  background: #666;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  display: block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  margin: 0 5px;
  outline: 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.bx-wrapper .bx-pager.bx-default-pager a:hover,
.bx-wrapper .bx-pager.bx-default-pager a.active,
.bx-wrapper .bx-pager.bx-default-pager a:focus {
  background: #000;
}
.bx-wrapper .bx-pager-item,
.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto .bx-controls-auto-item {
  display: inline-block;
  *zoom: 1;
  *display: inline;
}
```

Comment: Please post the relevant JavaScript and possibly which BoxSlider Library or Plugin you are trying to use.

Comment: It's definitely bxSlider, probably 4.2.5 the most current build.

Answer (score 1):

You should try setting up each bxSlider individually. In your `js.js` file do this:

```
var wood = $(".wood").bxSlider();
var book = $(".book").bxSlider();
var bw   = $(".bw").bxSlider();
```

and in your HTML do this:

```
<ul class="wood">
  <li>.....

<ul class="book">
  <li>.....

<ul class="bw">
  <li>.....
```

<strike>Just a suggestion</strike>, if your using HTML5 (which you are with `<!doctype html>`), you shouldn't use`<center>` it's even deprecated in HTML4. Actually get rid of those `<center>` I'm pretty sure using HTML5 may totally reject rendering them hence the error code calling `<center>` `null`.

You also have this:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

<!-- image slider -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You only need one of them.

Once you have done those 3 things and it's still not fixed, I have one more idea.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help. I've uploaded my website with your edits but still I the same problem keeps occurring. I think I'm realizing that the Uncaught TypeError has something to do with ul tag I used in creating different subjects I put my art in. Is it bad to have one ul tag within another? Maybe the css is overriding the others?

Comment: @matthewolf bxSlider can run with a `ul` inside of it, but wouldn't advice deviation from basic configurations until you have a good grasp of the plugin's API. There is a problem with Chrome PC, it might involve this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4390134/failed-to-load-resource-under-chrome . I'm not 100% sure... Firefox PC works. I disabled Google Analytic and put ONE jquery script before the bxSlider script. All script is at the closing tag of `</body>` As a general rule I place CSS at the head and scripts at the bottom. Btw, there's a lot of duplicate IDs (e.g. `id="gifs"`) ..cont>

Comment: @matthewolf <...Cont > This is invalid. IDs must always be unique. I was going to change the duplicate IDs into Classes but there's so many of them I'll leave that up to you :P I also took that code from `js.js` and placed it on the bottom of the page. The less `<link>` and `<script>` (i.e. external files) the less HTTP requests. There's also 2 `<link>` to Google Fonts, which you should consolidate into one `<link>` and you should trim the font-weights to 2 or 3 (e.g. 200, 500, 900). So the next step is to go to the demo and copy the source, then upload it to your server.

Comment: @matthewolf http://glpjt.s3.amazonaws.com/test/mc5.html Oh, almost forgot, there's an error on this `<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="document.getElementById('light8').style.display='none';document.getElementById('fade8').style.display='none'" class="close">X</a>` I got to go to work, good luck. Btw, it loads REALLY slow, so use `Inspect Element` on the area where there's a bxSlider, it'll popup. If you still need help, I'll be around later in the evening. (UTC-7) PDT