# getting this net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE error in browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-chrome, ftp, paperclip

I used gem "paperclip" for upload images and gem "paperclip-storage-ftp" for store images on my own ftp server.I got success to upload multiple photos and it's saved in my database too without having error.

but when I go to show photos page there i can see some photos proper, But

some most of photos are broken, and i am getting so many error in browser console like this

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

help me if you have any solution for this.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you try this in another browser other than chrome?

Comment: yes in firefox same thing happens.

Comment: See if this answer helps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9590757/981183

Comment: I tried some solutions from  that which i related to my error but its not worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Process Your Images Asynchronously

#### The Problem

I had the same thing happening to me. I found out that uploading large files were not the issue, it was the processing of the files after the upload by Paperclip that was the problem.

The browser has no problem keeping the connecting alive when it is actively uploading (or downloading) a file, but Paperclip was taking too long to process the files after they were uploaded, which the browser interprets as nothing happening. So if that processing takes too long (~1 min) the browser thinks something went wrong and returns an `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`.

#### The Solution

I installed and implemented the wonderful **[delayed_paperclip](https://github.com/jrgifford/delayed_paperclip/)** gem, which pushes all the Paperclip processing to asynchronous tasks.

This means that once the files are uploaded, the request is completed and the browser gets an immediate response instead of waiting for Paperclip to process the files.

Problem solved.