# net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE: only on deployed version

Tags: reactjs, flask, axios

I get a net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE error:

- only on deployed version, not localhost
- other GET-requests work

It downloads all my files from the ftp-server but it returns an error.:(

Flask Backend:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
cors = CORS(app)

@app.route('/downloadftp', methods=['POST'])
@cross_origin()
def download_all_ftp_data():
    # connect to sever...
    # download files...
    for f in ftp.nlst():
         fhandle = open(f, 'wb')
         ftp.retrbinary('RETR ' + f, fhandle.write)

    ftp.quit()
   
    return 'OK 200'
```

React Frontend:

```
useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .post(`${process.env.REACT_APP_HOST}/downloadftp`, { content: "post" })
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res)
        setError(false)
      })
      .catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err)
        setError(true)
      })
  }, [])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is due to the amount of data to download as it is described here: [getting this net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE error in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33560288/getting-this-neterr-empty-response-error-in-browser)

The solution for my problems was creating a daemon thread. The response is sent directly after starting the background thread.

```
from multiprocessing import Process

@app.route('/downloadftp')
@cross_origin()
def get_all_ftp_data():
    """creates a daemon thread for downloading all files while the response it sent directly after starting the background thread."""
    daemon_process = Process(
        target=download_data_multiprocessing,
        daemon=True
    )
    daemon_process.start()
    return Response(status=200)


def download_data_multiprocessing():
    """triggers download current data from ftp server"""
   
    # connect to sever
    # download
    for f in ftp.nlst():
        if (f != '.' and f != '..' and "meteo" not in f):
            fhandle = open(f, 'wb')
            ftp.retrbinary('RETR ' + f, fhandle.write)

    ftp.quit()
```