# In firefox jquery working fine, but not in chrome?

Tags: jquery

I have a problem please help me.

I'm creating two fields category and subcategory, based on user's select option in category field, options changed in subcategory for this write a code like this.

This code working fine in firefox but where as in chrome it is not working, I'm not sure why it's happening.

```js
$("#world").click(function(){
  $("#sub_article").html('<option value="">Select</option><option value="">Us</option><option value="">Chaina</option><option value="">Uk</option><option value="">Pakistan</option><option value="">Others</option>');
  $('#type_novel').html('');
});
$("#buss").click(function(){
  $("#sub_article").html('<option value="">Select</option><option value="">Indian business</option><option value="">International business</option><option value="">Markets</option><option value="">Shares</option><option value="">Others</option>');
  $('#type_novel').html('');
});
$("#tech").click(function(){
  $("#sub_article").html('<option value="">Select</option><option value="">Social</option><option value="">IT services</option><option value="">Mobiles & gadgets</option><option value="">Jobs</option><option value="">Others</option>');
  $('#type_novel').html('');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
  <span>Category :</span><select name="cat_article" id="cat_article">
  <option value="">Select</option>
  <option id="world" value="Job Inquiry">World news</option>
  <option id="buss" value="Job Inquiry">Business</option>
  <option id="tech" value="Job Inquiry">Technology</option>
  </select>
</label>
<label>
  <span>Sub category :</span><select name="sub_article" id="sub_article">
  <option value="">Select</option>
  </select>
</label>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<option>` tag isn't really supposed to support the `onclick` event (`.click` in jQuery) This is why you see it working in some browsers but not others.

Instead, set some meaningful values for the `value` attribute in your `<option>` tags, and then add a `.change` handler to the `<select>` tag.

For example:

```
$('#cat_article').change(function(){
        switch($(this).val()){
            case 'world':
                $("#sub_article").html('<option value="">Select</option><option value="">Us</option><option value="">Chaina</option><option value="">Uk</option><option value="">Pakistan</option><option value="">Others</option>');
                $('#type_novel').html('');
                break;
            case 'buss':
                 $("#sub_article").html('<option value="">Select</option><option value="">Indian business</option><option value="">International business</option><option value="">Markets</option><option value="">Shares</option><option value="">Others</option>');
                $('#type_novel').html('');
                break;
            case 'tech':
                $("#sub_article").html('<option value="">Select</option><option value="">Social</option><option value="">IT services</option><option value="">Mobiles & gadgets</option><option value="">Jobs</option><option value="">Others</option>');
                $('#type_novel').html('');
                break;
        }
    });
```

HTML:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
  <span>Category :</span><select name="cat_article" id="cat_article">
  <option value="">Select</option>
  <option value="world">World news</option>
  <option value="buss">Business</option>
  <option value="tech">Technology</option>
  </select>
</label>
<label>
  <span>Sub category :</span><select name="sub_article" id="sub_article">
  <option value="">Select</option>
  </select>
</label>
```

Comment: Thanks for supporting, its working fine. nice to catch you.

Answer (score 0):

You have some errors that are being produced in Chrome.  Hit F12 and open up the Chrome console and you'll see 3 errors

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT http://static.adzerk.net/Extensions/adFeedback.js
>
> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
>   http://static.adzerk.net/Extensions/adFeedback.css
>
> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
>   http://engine.adzerk.net/i.gif?e=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&s=myHyTjnpAWqzwqAn7qRey9LzIe4

This will give you a start to what is going on.  You might then go to this link which may shed some light on the situation.

> [Failed to load resource under Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4390134/failed-to-load-resource-under-chrome)