# developer tools does not loads resources

Tags: ionic2

When I run my ionic project to my mobile it was working good, and when I open developer tools it's fine.

I could able to view all console statement in my developer tool window, now when I run it again app runs well in the browser and in my mobile , I am not able to see any console statement.

What I get is

```
device ready has not fired after 5 seconds.
cordova.js:1223
Failed to load resource
file:///android_asset/www/build/index.js.map
```

could someone help me to view my console statements

Comment: what you re using for debugging .. google chrome ?

Comment: ya exactly chrome dont know how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

This should be fixed in cordova-android 6.1.0. It has not been added to the npm-registry yet, so you can use it by placing this to your config.xml:

```
<engine name="android" spec="https://github.com/apache/cordova-android.git#6.1.0"/>
```

Comment: should i need to add this to a specific tag in config .xml

Comment: no use add it here  <access origin="*"/>  <engine > <allow-navigation> @Chetann