# JavaScript file shows failed status in developer tools

Tags: javascript, caching, runtime, developer-tools, failed-to-connect

When I make a request (`https://something.com`), some of the JavaScript files are not loading. I can see failed status on developer tools in Google Chrome.

We are loading these JavaScript files on runtime on the fly. If I pull it by IP instead of `https://something.com`, I don't see the issue. I see all the requests are successful in the proxy logs which made sure that proxy is not blocking anything.

If I hit the JavaScript file directly on a browser, it opens fine. But only on runtime somehow the JavaScript files are failing to load. We are clearing the browser side cache as well as the load balancer cache to make sure it's not caching the files.

Has anyone faced this kind of issues before? If yes, what are the root causes that might be happening for this issue?

Comment: We need more information here. Screenshots/console error logs, steps to reproduce the issue. See [MCVE].

Comment: Adding the screenshots. But the only reason i want to know is why the js files are showing failed status with no response code like 200 or 400 or 500 but with failed. @FrankerZ

Comment: Try looking at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4390134/failed-to-load-resource-under-chrome