# HTML how to embed a picture using Flask?

Tags: html, flask

I am setting up a web app with flask. I try to show remote pictures
Flask replaces {{article["image"]}} with https://gitlab.com/MindReadH/Articles/raw/master/spain.png in the following code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>{{article.title}}</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{url_for('static',filename ='vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css')}}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{url_for('static',filename ='fonts/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css')}}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{url_for('static',filename ='css/articleDetail.css')}}"/>
    </head>

        <body>
        <div class="container">

            <center><a href="{{url_for('get_article_list',category=category,page=1)}}"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left fa-3x"></i></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="{{url_for('user_index')}}"><i class="fa fa-home fa-3x"></i></a></center>
            <div class="card mb-4">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h2 class="card-title" align="center">{{ article['title'] }}</h2>
                    <p align="center" class="card-text">{{ article['abstract']}}</p>
                    <p align="center" class="card-text">Category : {{ article['category']}}</p>
                    <p align="center" class="card-text">Article Tags : {{ article['articleTags']}}</p>
                    <p align="center" class="card-text">Authors : {{ article['authors']}}</p>
                    <p align="center" class="card-text">Language : {{ article['language']}}</p>
                    <p align="center" class="card-text">Text : {{ article['text']}}</p>
                    <img src={{article['text']}} class="inline"/>
                    <p align="center" class="inline-text">Image : {{ article['image']}}</p>
                    <img src={{article['image']}} class="inline"/>
                    <p align="center" class="card-text">Video : {{ article['video']}}</p>
                    <video controls><source src={{article['video']}}class="inline"/></video>
                </div>
                <!--<img class="card-img-top" src="http://placehold.it/750x300" alt="Card image cap">-->
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

As expected, the first line

```
<p align="center" class="inline-text">Image : {{ article['image']}}</p
```

returns
    Image : https://gitlab.com/MindReadH/Articles/raw/master/spain.png which is the address of the image

But the image is not loaded with the second line. Firefox log says:
"loading of all possible resources failed"

**Edit**

as Luis Melo pointed out, i just missed the quotation marks on the src file:

```
<img src="{{article['image']}}" class="inline"/>
```

Comment: for me it works perfectly fine, every image from github loads, maybe you should try replacing {{ with {!! ?

Comment: Does the image load in another browser?

Comment: Maybe some of your extensions are blocking it to load, if you have some adBlocker or something. https://stackoverflow.com/a/9590757/9871463

Comment: as Luis said, it was just the lack of quotation marks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are not using [quotation](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/objects.html#h-13.2) in your html.

Try replacing every **src** and **href** like these:

```
<img src={{article['image']}} class="inline"/>
```

With parameters with quotation:

```
<img src="{{article['image']}}" class="inline"/>
```

You can visualize the solution working [here](http://docker.lhsm.com.br/e6932b72-8729-4168-9224-877f15056ab9) along with the same issue you are facing.

Comment: So it turns out this problem is independant from the picture origin. thanks