# AWS Errors on homepage

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-chrome

I have a tremendous number of errors when I login on my aws homepage. Here's what inspect element shows

```
awsc-head.js:2     POST https://us-west-1.ccs.amazonaws.com/GetCallerSettings 403 (Forbidden)
o @ awsc-head.js:2
handle @ client23.js:1
await in handle (async)
(anonymous) @ client23.js:3
(anonymous) @ client23.js:3
(anonymous) @ client23.js:3
await in (anonymous) (async)
(anonymous) @ client23.js:3
await in (anonymous) (async)
(anonymous) @ client23.js:3
await in (anonymous) (async)
(anonymous) @ client23.js:3
(anonymous) @ client23.js:3
(anonymous) @ client23.js:3
(anonymous) @ client23.js:3
await in (anonymous) (async)
(anonymous) @ client23.js:3
send @ client23.js:1
sendCommand @ index4.js:1
await in sendCommand (async)
(anonymous) @ module-metadata.js:1
await in (anonymous) (async)
(anonymous) @ module2.js:1
emit @ translations.js:13
(anonymous) @ translations.js:86
emit @ translations.js:13
handleMessageReceived @ translations.js:17
r @ translations.js:17
a @ translations.js:17
(anonymous) @ translations.js:17
Promise.then (async)
deliverMessage @ translations.js:17
(anonymous) @ translations.js:86
deliverMessage @ translations.js:17
sendAskMessage @ translations.js:17
fr @ module-metadata.js:1
_e @ module-metadata.js:1
(anonymous) @ module-metadata.js:4
await in (anonymous) (async)
emit @ translations.js:13
(anonymous) @ translations.js:86
emit @ translations.js:13
handleMessageReceived @ translations.js:17
r @ translations.js:17
a @ translations.js:17
(anonymous) @ translations.js:17
Promise.then (async)
deliverMessage @ translations.js:17
(anonymous) @ translations.js:86
deliverMessage @ translations.js:17
sendAskMessage @ translations.js:17
Dv @ module-resolver.js:3
getResults @ module-resolver.js:96
(anonymous) @ module-resolver.js:3
await in (anonymous) (async)
r @ module-resolver.js:3
iQ @ module-resolver.js:96
(anonymous) @ module-resolver.js:96
(anonymous) @ module-resolver.js:105
emit @ module-resolver.js:1
(anonymous) @ module-resolver.js:1
emit @ translations.js:13
handleMessageReceived @ translations.js:17
r @ translations.js:17
a @ translations.js:17
(anonymous) @ translations.js:17
Promise.then (async)
deliverMessage @ translations.js:17
(anonymous) @ translations.js:86
deliverMessage @ translations.js:17
sendAskMessage @ translations.js:17
EZe @ module-resolver.js:116
kXe @ module-resolver.js:143
await in kXe (async)
activate @ module-resolver.js:143
d @ translations.js:17
await in d (async)
h @ translations.js:17
deliverMessage @ translations.js:17
(anonymous) @ translations.js:86
deliverMessage @ translations.js:17
w @ translations.js:17
(anonymous) @ index.js:1
H @ index.js:1
await in H (async)
(anonymous) @ index.js:358
await in (anonymous) (async)
(anonymous) @ index.js:358
awsc-head.js:2     POST https://us-west-1.ccs.amazonaws.com/GetCallerDashboard 403 (Forbidden)
o @ awsc-head.js:2
handle @ module-metadata.js:4
(anonymous) @ client23.js:3
(anonymous) @ client23.js:3
(anonymous) @ client23.js:3
await in (anonymous) (async)
(anonymous) @ client23.js:3
await in (anonymous) (async)
(anonymous) @ client23.js:3
await in (anonymous) (async)
(anonymous) @ client23.js:3
(anonymous) @ client23.js:3
(anonymous) @ client23.js:3
(anonymous) @ client23.js:3
await in (anonymous) (async)
(anonymous) @ client23.js:3
send @ client23.js:1
sendCommand @ index4.js:1
await in sendCommand (async)
(anonymous) @ module-metadata.js:1
await in (anonymous) (async)
(anonymous) @ module2.js:1
emit @ translations.js:13
(anonymous) @ translations.js:86
emit @ translations.js:13
handleMessageReceived @ translations.js:17
r @ translations.js:17
a @ translations.js:17
(anonymous) @ translations.js:17
Promise.then (async)
deliverMessage @ translations.js:17
(anonymous) @ translations.js:86
deliverMessage @ translations.js:17
sendAskMessage @ translations.js:17
fr @ module-metadata.js:1
_e @ module-metadata.js:1
(anonymous) @ module-metadata.js:4
await in (anonymous) (async)
emit @ translations.js:13
(anonymous) @ translations.js:86
emit @ translations.js:13
handleMessageReceived @ translations.js:17
r @ translations.js:17
a @ translations.js:17
(anonymous) @ translations.js:17
Promise.then (async)
deliverMessage @ translations.js:17
(anonymous) @ translations.js:86
deliverMessage @ translations.js:17
sendAskMessage @ translations.js:17
Dv @ module-resolver.js:3
getResults @ module-resolver.js:96
(anonymous) @ module-resolver.js:3
await in (anonymous) (async)
r @ module-resolver.js:3
iQ @ module-resolver.js:96
(anonymous) @ module-resolver.js:96
(anonymous) @ module-resolver.js:105
emit @ module-resolver.js:1
(anonymous) @ module-resolver.js:1
emit @ translations.js:13
handleMessageReceived @ translations.js:17
r @ translations.js:17
a @ translations.js:17
(anonymous) @ translations.js:17
Promise.then (async)
deliverMessage @ translations.js:17
(anonymous) @ translations.js:86
deliverMessage @ translations.js:17
sendAskMessage @ translations.js:17
EZe @ module-resolver.js:116
kXe @ module-resolver.js:143
await in kXe (async)
activate @ module-resolver.js:143
d @ translations.js:17
await in d (async)
h @ translations.js:17
deliverMessage @ translations.js:17
(anonymous) @ translations.js:86
deliverMessage @ translations.js:17
w @ translations.js:17
(anonymous) @ index.js:1
H @ index.js:1
await in H (async)
(anonymous) @ index.js:358
await in (anonymous) (async)
(anonymous) @ index.js:358
awsc-head.js:2     POST https://us-west-1.ccs.amazonaws.com/GetCallerSettings 403 (Forbidden)
o @ awsc-head.js:2
handle @ client23.js:1
await in handle (async)
(anonymous) @ client23.js:3
(anonymous) @ client23.js:3
(anonymous) @ client23.js:3
await in (anonymous) (async)
(anonymous) @ client23.js:3
await in (anonymous) (async)
(anonymous) @ client23.js:3
await in (anonymous) (async)
(anonymous) @ client23.js:3
(anonymous) @ client23.js:3
(anonymous) @ client23.js:3
(anonymous) @ client23.js:3
await in (anonymous) (async)
(anonymous) @ client23.js:3
send @ client23.js:1
sendCommand @ index4.js:1
await in sendCommand (async)
(anonymous) @ module-metadata.js:1
await in (anonymous) (async)
(anonymous) @ module2.js:1
emit @ translations.js:13
(anonymous) @ translations.js:86
emit @ translations.js:13
handleMessageReceived @ translations.js:17
deliverMessage @ translations.js:17
(anonymous) @ translations.js:86
deliverMessage @ translations.js:17
sendAskMessage @ translations.js:17
fr @ module-metadata.js:1
_e @ module-metadata.js:1
(anonymous) @ module-metadata.js:4
await in (anonymous) (async)
emit @ translations.js:13
(anonymous) @ translations.js:86
emit @ translations.js:13
handleMessageReceived @ translations.js:17
deliverMessage @ translations.js:17
(anonymous) @ translations.js:86
deliverMessage @ translations.js:17
sendAskMessage @ translations.js:17
Ao @ module.6c0a17d2.js:1
(anonymous) @ module.6c0a17d2.js:4
emit @ contribution-points.8a8a677c.js:1
(anonymous) @ contribution-points.8a8a677c.js:1
emit @ translations.js:13
handleMessageReceived @ translations.js:17
deliverMessage @ translations.js:17
(anonymous) @ translations.js:86
deliverMessage @ translations.js:17
sendAskMessage @ translations.js:17
Ao @ module.6c0a17d2.js:1
b_ @ module.6c0a17d2.js:37
(anonymous) @ module.6c0a17d2.js:88
await in (anonymous) (async)
emit @ contribution-points.8a8a677c.js:1
(anonymous) @ contribution-points.8a8a677c.js:1
emit @ translations.js:13
handleMessageReceived @ translations.js:17
r @ translations.js:17
a @ translations.js:17
(anonymous) @ translations.js:17
Promise.then (async)
deliverMessage @ translations.js:17
(anonymous) @ translations.js:86
deliverMessage @ translations.js:17
sendAskMessage @ translations.js:17
Ap @ translations.js:86
await in Ap (async)
(anonymous) @ translations.js:86
emit @ translations.js:13
(anonymous) @ translations.js:86
emit @ translations.js:13
handleMessageReceived @ translations.js:17
r @ translations.js:17
a @ translations.js:17
(anonymous) @ translations.js:17
Promise.then (async)
deliverMessage @ translations.js:17
(anonymous) @ translations.js:86
deliverMessage @ translations.js:17
w @ translations.js:17
(anonymous) @ index.js:1
H @ index.js:1
await in H (async)
(anonymous) @ index.js:358
await in (anonymous) (async)
(anonymous) @ index.js:358
```

I've tried many of the solutions here: [Failed to load resource under Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4390134/failed-to-load-resource-under-chrome) including using clear cache on the network tab, trying another browser, and turning off all my chrome extensions and nothing has worked.

Comment: Have you tried changing widgets or actually writing to AWS support?

Comment: Yes, I moved around the widgets, but that didn't seem to help. And yes, I have written to aws support under billing and account and I got another error that said "can't process request" or something like that, but I did actually get a confirmation email that a ticket was created... so maybe it did go through. I'm considering just starting again by setting up another account with a different email.

Comment: Browser extensions? Does a different machine yield the same errors?